# PowerShell Foreach Loop with Variable for User Accounts to Copy File

Tags: powershell, foreach, robocopy, xcopy

I'm trying to copy a file to a list of users' folders on a network share using a foreach loop and a variable containing all of the user names. This is what I've done so far with no success. I understand *why* it's not working (loading all usernames at once in the variable), but I'm not sure what to do to correct it, or if a foreach loop is the best route to take. I've tried a lot of variations of the below and done a lot of googling.

```
$whusers = "username1", "username2", "username3"

Foreach ($user in $whusers) {
xcopy "C:\users\myname\desktop\shortcut.url" "F:\corp users\$whusers\desktop" }
```

Any help would be great appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a ForEach loop, you are iterating through all elements of the 2nd variable and putting them in turn into the first.  Inside the ForEach, you must reference the **first** variable, not the second.  Change the `$whusers` inside your ForEach to `$user$`.

Try this:

```
$whusers = "username1","username2","username3"

Foreach ($user in $whusers) {
    xcopy "C:\users\myname\desktop\shortcut.url" "F:\corp users\$user\desktop"
}
```

Comment: Great but there is native Copy-Item cmdlet then why we should use xcopy?

Answer (score 0):

Even this can done withou using the $user variable. ForEach is used to iterate over an array.
If the object to iterate over is piped as input, there is a special variable $_ to act as each time as the element of an array.

```
$whusers = "username1", "username2", "username3"

$whusers | ForEach {
xcopy "C:\users\myname\desktop\shortcut.url" "F:\corp users\$_\desktop" 
}
```